# Sequelize: get MIN/MAX Dates from association

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have to tables - one for events and another one for the dates (start-end) this event is "active".

```
id   name  
--   ----
1    event 1
2    event 2
```

And then the EventDates

```
eventId   start         end
-------   -----         ---
1         2018-01-14    2018-01-15
1         2018-01-17    2018-01-18
2         2018-02-14    2018-02-18
```

Events and EventDates are setup using `hasMany()`

```
Event.DATES = Event.hasMany(models.EventDates, {
  as: 'dates',
  foreignKey: 'eventId',
});
```

Querying for all Events including the EventDates like this:

```
await Event.findAll({
  include: [{ association: Event.DATES }]
});
```

returns a nested Event list with all the EventDates - great.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'event 1',
    dates: [
      {
        start: '2018-01-14',
        end: '2018-01-15',
      },
      {
        start: '2018-01-17',
        end: '2018-01-18',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'event 2',
    dates: [
      {
        start: '2018-02-14',
        end: '2018-02-18',
      },
    ],
  }
]
```

But now I want to add a maxEndDate to an Event so I can check if it still active or if all EventDates are in the past. I can do that manually adding another `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
# ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT eventId, MAX(end) 
                 FROM `EventDates` 
                 GROUP BY eventId) dates 
   ON `Event`.`id` = `dates`.`eventId`
# ...
```

But how could I achieve the same thing with Sequelize?

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'event 1',
    maxEndDate: ??,
    dates: [
      {
        start: '2018-01-14',
        end: '2018-01-15',
      },
      {
        start: '2018-01-17',
        end: '2018-01-18',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'event 2',
    maxEndDate: ??,
    dates: [
      {
        start: '2018-02-14',
        end: '2018-02-18',
      },
    ],
  }
]
```

Comment: Will you please check the answer?

Answer (score -1):

It very tricky to get result with group by and has many association , but at last I found the way and here it is :

```
Event.findAll({
  raw : true,
  attributes : [ 'Event.*' , 'EventDates.eventId' , [sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('EventDates.end')),'end']],
  include : {
      model : EventDates ,
      attributes :[]
    },
    group : ['Event.id','EventDates.eventId']
})
```

I think you can achieve your last out put that by this , I haven't tried this but this is the way you can go ahead

```
Event.findAll({
      raw : true,
      attributes : [ 'Event.*' , 'dates.*' , 'EventDates.eventId' , [sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('EventDates.end')),'end']],
      include : [
            {
                model : EventDates ,
                attributes :[]
            },
            {
                model : EventDates ,
                as : 'dates',
                required : false,
                separate : true
            }
        ]
        group : ['Event.id','EventDates.eventId']
    })
```

Comment: could you add some more explanations? what does the raw: true do? etc

Comment: `raw: true` will return plain data and not the instance of the sequlize , `sequelize.fn` is to execute any sql function , rest of the things you know , right ?

Comment: thanks. wasn't just for me but anyone reading your answer. it is working but you removed all the attributes to make it work. I want the Event.DATES columns as well as the `MAX(end)`. I was hoping to get both but that is maybe only possible with a manual query ...

Comment: @pkyeck , I have also updated answer please check that also , that might help you